# Finding specific gravity of a plank

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

A wooden plank is floating on water in a pool. It is tethered to the bottom of the pool by a string attached at mid-point of an edge of its bottom face, which causes it to float with a diagonal of one of its vertical cross-section coinciding with the level surface of the water, as shown in the figure. What is the specific gravity of the wood?

What I have done is finding the point of application of buoyant force and gravitational force and took the torque about the point where tension is being applied so that I dont have to deal with it but the solution is coming variable dependent.

[image]

Comment: Show what you've done and maybe we can help you.

Comment: So sorry I just checked it. It was just a minor calculation error. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: @Krishna Not to worry. This was a fun question anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you have created *artificially* a gradient of $g$ on the plane of the wood plank. The gradient is the slope $S$ of the plank plane to the horizontal.

$$S=tanθ=α/β$$

with,

$$g(x)=g(1+Sdx/x)$$

for $dx=0, g(x)=g$
for $dx=x, g(x)=g(1+S)$

where $g=9.81 m/s^2$ the gravitational acceleration of Earth.

[image: artificail g gradient]